# make background transition fast on focus/active click but slow on release

Tags: jquery, css

Want the `li` to fast/instantly get red highlight(`background-color`) when clicked , and lose the red highlight slowly.
Is there a way to accomplish this with only css using `:active`? or do i need to go with jquery `addClass`, `setTimeOut, removeClass`

this is what i have so far but ofc it is transitioning in at the transition speed

```
<ul id="kren">
    <li>Text Text Text</li>
     <li>Text Text Text</li>
        <li>Text Text Text</li>
        <li>Text Text Text</li>
        <li>Text Text Text</li>
</ul>

<style>
#kren {list-style:none; }
li {display:block; border: thin black solid; width: 250px; }
li:active {background-color:red; transition: background-color, .5s;}
.red {background-color:red;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then you add the transition speed you want going back to the li like so:

```
li {display:block; border: thin black solid; width: 250px; transition: background-color, 2s;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it like so

```
li:active {background-color:white; 
     -webkit-animation: play .8s steps(100) none;
       -moz-animation: play .8s steps(100) none;
        -ms-animation: play .8s steps(100) none;
         -o-animation: play .8s steps(100) none;
            animation: play .8s steps(100) none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes play {
   from { background-color:red; }
     to { background-color:white; }
}

@keyframes play {
   from { background-color:red; }
     to { background-color:white; }
}
```

Based on:
  http://css-tricks.com/steps/
and the link therein
  http://jsfiddle.net/simurai/CGmCe/.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/25yrmv5w/1/)**

**Edit:** I am not shure if this is the action you want to achieve, since you state "after release" in your question. Here you have to *hold*.